# Creating sub child Business Units in the Enterprise

Tags: marketing-cloud

Let's assume I create two BU'S under the root one. Then under each BU's, I create two children BU's under each BU. For my prospective, it will be very challenging to query and have shareable assets? Any suggestion?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more specific so that can be answered. See the link for how to structure your questions https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When creating Business United Under the Parent. I will create two Business United (Example Unitedhealth, and OptumHealth). Now under each of these united, I will four BU's UnitedHealth US, UnitedHealth Br, UnitedHealth CA, UnitedHleath AU. Same thing under OptumHealth OptumHealth US, OptumHealth Br, OptumHealth CA, OptumHealth AUS. Hence, I have three levels. My question is how challenging will be to have SQl queried, Ampscripts and use communication between the Sub BU's with parents? Is it Good approach?

Answer (score 1):

Creation of business units is to provide separation of data and for Branding. A few things I would think about before deciding whether to go with Business units are :

1. Do your business units need special branding considerations - different logos, company addresses, IP addresses. If yes, Business units are needed.
2. How are your marketing cloud users going to be set up to access information - if you intend separate user groups to work on each unit, then it makes sense for the BU separation.
3. Data source - are you using Salesforce CRM integration? If yes, then is your data coming from a single CRM instance or separate instances of each of the BUs. One business unit can connect to only 1 CRM instance so that should factor into the BU hierarchy.
4. Cost - Each Business unit comes with an additional cost, unless you already have a enterprise license. Is it worth the extra cost.

Coming to your specific questions

- SQL queries - The data extensions are visible at the root level, you can use the prefix ENT. before the "Data-Extension-Name" to reference child BU Data extensions
- Content can be shared using the shared folder feature.

In my opinion, go with BUs only if it's absolutely necessary to maintain the separation. The whole point for BUs is to separate and it's counterproductive to find ways to have separate BUs and then make them share information. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I understand your point. We have Enterprise edition an you are talking about having different BU. However, my case is you have three levels. First level is the root, second is the brand third level which are the children are the BU's of each brand country

Comment: Marketing Cloud let's you create multiple levels in the BU hierarchy, but there's little advantage in doing this, other than to visualise how the BUs are "related". In reality, there's nothing that binds the BUs on one branch and it' can actually a little problematic from a provisioning standpoint where the child BU doesn't pick up the Business Rules of its parent. You'll more often see all child BUs arranged on a single level. It can be done, though.